# Android: How to set substrings in lowercase in my string?

Tags: android, string

I want to set all my hashtags in lowercase in a string:

> "Hello I'm a men **#Athlete** et I'm going to do sport **#NeverGiveUp**"

Should become:

> "Hello I'm a men **#athlete** et I'm going to
>   do sport **#nevergiveup**"

Comment: Did you try .toLowerCase?

Comment: isn't there method called `toLowerCase()` for String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your problem is how to convert all to simple letters hope this helps

```
String myString = "HashTag";
  String myNewSimpleLetterString = myString.substring(0,5).toLowerCase(); //subString will get the characters from 0 - 5
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

Just pass your string to this method this method returns formatted String

```
public static String changeFormat(String beforeFormatStr) {
    String[] arrStr = beforeFormatStr.split(" ");
    String afterFormatStr = "";
    int wordPos = 0;
    for (String word : arrStr) {
        String changeStr = word;
        if (word.contains("#")) {
            changeStr = word.toLowerCase();
        }
        if (wordPos == 0) {
            afterFormatStr += changeStr;
        } else {
            afterFormatStr += " " + changeStr;
        }
        wordPos++;
    }
    return afterFormatStr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular expression for finding and replacing hashtags to lowercase. Like :

```
    String line = "Hello I'm a men #Athlete et I'm going to do sport #NeverGiveUp";
    String regEx = "\\S*#(?:\\[[^\\]]+\\]|\\S+)"; //Regular expression for matching hashtag

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regEx);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);

    while (m.find())
    {
        // Avoids throwing a NullPointerException in the case that you
        // Don't have a replacement defined in the map for the match
        String repString = m.group();
        if (repString != null)
            repString = repString.toLowerCase();
            m.appendReplacement(sb, repString);
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    String replacedHashtag = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hash is not a string, so you have to use Regx matcher and Pattern to achieve this.

```
 List<String> obtained_hashwords = new ArrayList<>();

        String text_data = "Hello I'm a men #Athlete et I'm going to do sport #NeverGiveUp  and I want to format this string";


        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("#\\w+");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text_data);
        while (matcher.find())
        {
            obtained_hashwords.add(matcher.group());
            Log.d("Hash word",matcher.group());

        }
        for (String obtained_hashword:obtained_hashwords)
        {
             String no_hash = obtained_hashword.replace("#","");
             String lower_case_word = "#"+no_hash.toLowerCase();
          text_data  = text_data.replace(obtained_hashword,lower_case_word);
        }

        Log.d("changed line",text_data);
```